# How to disable some Log functions when building an Android app?

Tags: android, logging

I use Log functions to debug my Android app. I'm close to releasing my app and I'd like to reduce debug level. However I don't know how to disable some of these function. Say I just want to disable Log.v() logs.

Android doc says [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html) that one should remove Log functions calls in code or remove/set to false the android::debbugable option. The first option does not fit my needs, since I'd like to Log calls in my source code (for future updates). The second option disables all logs, which is not convenient for pre-release testing.

Do you know how to disable only verbose (Log.v) logs ?

Many thanks!

Comment: I would replace Log.v with //Log.v in all the project

Comment: remove all log items in your code that would work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your own wrapper for the `Log`-class, maybe something like this:

```
static class MyLog{
    private static int mLevel;
    public final static void setLevel(int level){
        mLevel = level;
    }
    public final static void v(String tag, String message){
        if( mLevel > 0 ) return;
        Log.v(tag, message);
    }
    public final static void d(String tag, String message){
        if( mLevel > 1 ) return;
        Log.d(tag, message);
    }
    public final static void i(String tag, String message){
        if( mLevel > 2 ) return;
        Log.d(tag, message);
    }
    //Same for w and e if neccessary..
}
```

Then you can use `MyLog.setLevel(1);` to disable any verbose logging (or a higher level to disable those logs as well).

Comment: Nice and easy, thank you! From your answer and the other one, I understand there is no build-in solution. I thought that was the purpose of having 5 different functions. Are they just here for aesthetics ?

Comment: @Cyctemic There might be, although if one exists I haven't found it yet. If you are viewing the log output in LogCat you can choose to filter out logs of certain levels, so they aren't completely 'useless'.  
You can read a bit about the logging here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to obfuscate your release with Proguard, then putting lines such as

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}
```

into the config file will remove those categories of logging from your code.

Comment: I didn't plan on using Proguard, but I keep your idea in a corner of my mind, as it may be useful on other plans I have. Thanks :)